# Deploy EF6 web application

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, razor, entity-framework-6

I have developed a website/application in Razor c# (without MVC). I am using EF6. When I run the website locally it works fine, also writing/reading from database works perfect. I wanted to deploy my website to my webserver which I'm running at home.

I have backed-up the local database and restored it on my webserver (so it has the same database). I copied all the code incl. references to my webserver. It shows no errors and run all the pages except the pages that contains EF6 code. When I try to create an account on my application the application hangs and will stuck loading.. It returns no errors, it just loads infinitely.

Is there a way to deploy all my EF6 files and all the code correctly to my webserver? I think it doesn't work when I just copy all of the files and change connection string to the one on the server..

Comment: Sounds like it might be a permissions issue. Assuming you are not using trusted_connection, have you created the sql server login that you had locally on the remote sql instance (this wont go as part of a backup, you'll just get an orphaned user in the restored database).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This could be the problem (if I was using a sql authentication method) but I'm using the Windows Authentication method (in my connection string Integrated Security=True), this is for my local db as my server db as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, this topic can be closed, I found the issue. It was indeed a permission issue, but the page didn't return that error. I was using integrated security and it works on my iisexpress session, but when I made a custom IIS website locally and added it to my hostfile, it returned an error that the user IISPOOL/myprojectname could not login. Unfortonately i haven't got this message on my server :)